# Tor: fputs of "SIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n" results in empty response from fread

Tags: php, curl, tor

does anyone please know why

```
fputs($fp, "SIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n");
$response = fread($fp, 1024);
```

return an empty $response (on windows)? i can't get it to work after 5 hours trying everything
i use the code in:

```
$fp = fsockopen('localhost', 9051, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    $auth_code = 'a-password';
    if ($fp) {
        echo "Connected to TOR port<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo "Cant connect to TOR port<br />";
    }

    fputs($fp, "AUTHENTICATE \"".$auth_code."\"\r\n");
    $response = fread($fp, 1024);
    list($code, $text) = explode(' ', $response, 2);
    if ($code = '250') {
        echo "Authenticated 250 OK<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo "Authentication failed<br />";
    }

    fputs($fp, "SIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n");
    $response = fread($fp, 1024);
```

it is my goal to have TOR usinga new ip for every request

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that authentication is failing and the connection is being closed so the subsequent `fputs` and `fread` for the NEWNYM signal are just returning `false`.

In your check of the authenticate response, there is a logic error here:

```
if ($code = '250') {
```

To compare `$code` to `250`, you need to use `==`.

If the auth fails, this evaluates to true tricking you into thinking you authenticated when it may have failed.

Authentication may be failing because the password is simply incorrect, or only cookie authentication is supported.

---

Side note, I have created a PHP library you may be interested in called [TorUtils](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/) which provides classes for communication with the Tor [control](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/tc_GetInfo.php) port, and also a [cURL wrapper](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/CurlWrapper.php) for ensuring cURL requests properly go through Tor's SOCKS proxy.

Using the curl wrapper and control client, your code can easily wrap curl requests through Tor and issue commands to the control port to request a new IP.

Answer (score 1):

You are right!
sometimes it takes like 8 seconds before an new ip is optained.
logs:
Jan 16 18:27:54.000 [notice] Rate limiting NEWNYM request: delaying by 3 second(s)
Jan 16 18:28:00.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
Jan 16 18:28:00.000 [notice] Rate limiting NEWNYM request: delaying by 7 second(s)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks drew010!  you where right, i was not authenticated. Now i am.

However, with code below, each time i run this script, it fetches http://www.watismijnip.nl with a different ip.
But it needs to us a new ip, after each fetching of page. This is not the case now.

I realise that a new identity is required wih port 9051, while curl uses port 9050. But if i let curl use port 9051, it give and empty string back.

Can can that be done?

```
    function tor_new_identity($tor_ip='127.0.0.1', $control_port='9051', $auth_code=''){
    $fp = fsockopen($tor_ip, $control_port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) return false; //can't connect to the control port

    fputs($fp, "AUTHENTICATE $auth_code\r\n");
    $response = fread($fp, 1024);
    echo 'debug: $response='.$response."\n<br>";
    list($code, $text) = explode(' ', $response, 2);
    if ($code != '250') return false; //authentication failed

    //send the request to for new identity
    fputs($fp, "signal NEWNYM\r\n");
    $response = fread($fp, 1024);
    list($code, $text) = explode(' ', $response, 2);
    if ($code != '250') return false; //signal failed

    fclose($fp);
    return true;
}


if (tor_new_identity('127.0.0.1', '9051', '"my_password"')) {
    echo "Identity switched!";
}else{
    echo "Identity NOT switched!";
}

$url='http://www.watismijnip.nl/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
print_r($curl_error);


if (tor_new_identity('127.0.0.1', '9051', '"my_password"')) {
    echo "Identity switched!";
}else{
    echo "Identity NOT switched!";
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
print_r($curl_error);
```

Comment: :Tor needs 5 second pause between identy check. Can you post the log files?